# Why does this error appear when I try to run Spyder on Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I get an error whenever I try to run Spyder on Anaconda. I reinstalled more than 5 times and tried to fix Windows' variables path but it does not work at all.

Could anyone help me fix this problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in 
from spyder.app.start import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 62, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 32, in 
raise original_error from None
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 32, in select_backend
mod = import_module(name)
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in 
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially 
initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a 
circular import) 
(C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This happens because you installed some package using `pip` into this directory:

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python`

So the solution is to remove that directory completely and Spyder will start again without problems.

Comment: I'm really glad! Could you mark my answer as correct then? You can do that by clicking on the green check mark to the left. That would be helpful for other people encountering the same problem.